# Not able to print correct List (java.util) size

Tags: java, webdriver

I have tried this sample program and everytime I run it, it is giving "zero items in the list". I have tried sleep also, just to avoid the doubt that page ran so fast that it couldn't find the element.

What wrong I am doing?

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("test");
        List<WebElement> allElements = driver
                .findElements(By
                        .xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li"));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("there are "+allElements.size()+" items in this list");
```

PS:I am new in JAVA programming.

Comment: Have you considered that it's more likely to be your XPath that's failing than a `List.size()` implementation? Also, sleeping *after* you've created the list is unlikely to help...

Comment: Ahh its a typo mistake putting sleep in wrong place and I think the xpath is correct.

Comment: Adding sleeps into non-working code doesn't magically fix it. It only manifests inexperience.

Comment: @paul: You *think* the XPath is correct... that doesn't engender much confidence, to be honest. Are you able to output the doc that the driver is looking at? Have you tried your XPath expression against that doc? What is the node that the XPath expression is meant to be relative to?

Comment: @Skeet, which doc? how to try xpath expression against doc?

Comment: One thing I learned today about SOF and that is Guys having six figure reputation points on SOF, doesnt mean that they know everything. You should always wait for correct answer. I am saying this because xpath is absolutelyyyy correct. I have tested and it passed the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code xpath is absolutely right, there is no problem in it. It's just page went to fast that webdriver couldn't get proper time to get how many items are there as "li" i.e. size of the list.

 To correct that one way is to put a sleep which is not the most optimum way and 

 another way is to use `WebDriverWait`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable(By
                        .xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li")));
```

It should be before yuu want to store items in the list.

Comment: With all things webdriver, utilise the explicit wait. It saves so many headaches.

Comment: That was tried but it didn't work, did you try or posted the comment just like that per your experience.

Comment: What you've done above in your answer is use the explicit wait function. I'm backing up your answer by saying that what you've done is the correct action and it is what you should, in most cases, try before anything else.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood. I dont see any upvotes to my answer :)